# Qt Creator: different behavior of class template in Debug and Release modes

Tags: c++, qt, templates, build

I'm trying to specialize template member function. The problem is that in Debug mode calls specialization of method, but in Release calls non-specialized function.

For example, I have class template and specialized method

```
template <typename T>
class SimpleClass
{
public:
    void doSomething(const T& arg)
    {
        std::cout << "doSomething(const T& arg)" << std::endl;
    }
};
template <>
void SimpleClass<double>::doSomething(const double& arg)
{
    std::cout << "doSomething(const double& arg)" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SimpleClass<double> obj;
    obj.doSomething(1);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm expecting, that output will `"doSomething(const double& arg)"`.

So in Debug mode I got it, but in Release I got this: `"doSomething(const T& arg)"`

My question is why that code behave this way and how can I fix it?
Just in case, my .pro file

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
SOURCES += main.cpp \
    mathop.cpp
HEADERS += \
    mathop.h
```

edit: I'm using Qt 5.9.1

edit: forgot `#include <iostream>` before using `cout`

Comment: Can you try removing mathop.cpp and .h from your .pro file, and putting the code you are showing  us in your main.cpp please? (The current code won't compile because it is missing #include <iostream>).  I suspect the problem is in the code you aren't showing.

Answer (score 0):

As you're calling `doSomething()` with an integer as parameter, I guess the compiler is just trying to find an arbitrary match here. I can't say why debug and release builds behave differently, but I would expect it to work as expected when explicitely using a float value in the call:

```
obj.doSomething(1.0);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But nope, I tried to do it this way: `double d = 1.0; obj.doSomething(d);`